# Regular expression: match start or whitespace

Tags: python, regex

**Can a regular expression match whitespace *or* the start of a string?**

I'm trying to replace currency the abbreviation GBP with a £ symbol. I could just match anything starting GBP, but I'd like to be a bit more conservative, and look for certain delimiters around it.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = u'GBP 5 Off when you spend GBP75.00'

>>> re.sub(ur'GBP([\W\d])', ur'£\g<1>', text) # matches GBP with any prefix
u'\xa3 5 Off when you spend \xa375.00'

>>> re.sub(ur'^GBP([\W\d])', ur'£\g<1>', text) # matches at start only
u'\xa3 5 Off when you spend GBP75.00'

>>> re.sub(ur'(\W)GBP([\W\d])', ur'\g<1>£\g<2>', text) # matches whitespace prefix only
u'GBP 5 Off when you spend \xa375.00'
```

Can I do both of the latter examples at the same time?

Comment: Which language is this? Is it Perl?

Comment: Yes Python, but the concept is the same regardless.

Comment: Then how about tagging the question with "python", and maybe include it somewhere in the question? It would help others who don't know the language, and can help people when searching google.

Comment: I do normally, but regular expressions trangress languages to an extent. The question was more about the regular expression than the Python syntax.

Comment: Regex capabilities and syntax vary a great deal from one flavor to the next, so you should always include that info.  One thing that doesn't vary, though, is that \W matches anything that's not a word character, ie, [^A-Za-z0-9_]; the shorthand for whitespace is \s.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use the OR "`|`" operator:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(^|\W)GBP([\W\d])', u'\g<1>£\g<2>', text)
u'\xa3 5 Off when you spend \xa375.00'
```

Comment: Excellent. I'd assumed ^ was forced to be at the very beginning of the string. Minor change necessary to maintain the spacing: re.sub(u'(^|\W)GBP([\W\d])', u'\g<1>£\g<2>', text). Accepted due to being the most intuitive solution to my immediate problem.

Answer (score 73):

`\b` is word boundary, which can be a white space, the beginning of a line or a non-alphanumeric symbol (`\bGBP\b`).

Comment: Cool. I've learnt two things from your answer. 1. I've never used word boundaries in regular expressions before. 2. Things (particularly \b) don't work well if you accidentally use u'' rather than r'' prefixes on Python regular expressions.

Comment: Cool. That makes sense now you mention it.

Comment: This is much more useful, specifically it means you can do this without a group.

Comment: Just FYI, in postgres the word boundary indicator is \y instead of \b

Comment: Note `r'\bGBP'` matches `(BGP)`, `.GPB`, `=GBP` and many others which can be very useful but does not answer the question.

Answer (score 12):

A left-hand whitespace boundary - a position in the string that is either a string start or right after a whitespace character - can be expressed with

```
(?<!\S)   # A negative lookbehind requiring no non-whitespace char immediately to the left of the current position
(?<=\s|^) # A positive lookbehind requiring a whitespace or start of string immediately to the left of the current position
(?:\s|^)  # A non-capturing group matching either a whitespace or start of string 
(\s|^)    # A capturing group matching either a whitespace or start of string
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9TNlEp/1). [Python 3 demo](https://ideone.com/7vInLS):

```
import re
rx = r'(?<!\S)GBP([\W\d])'
text = 'GBP 5 Off when you spend GBP75.00'
print( re.sub(rx, r'£\1', text) )
# => £ 5 Off when you spend £75.00
```

Note you may use `\1` instead of `\g<1>` in the replacement pattern since there is no need in an unambiguous backreference when it is not followed with a digit.

BONUS: A right-hand whitespace boundary can be expressed with the following patterns:

```
(?!\S)   # A negative lookahead requiring no non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current position
(?=\s|$) # A positive lookahead requiring a whitespace or end of string immediately to the right of the current position
(?:\s|$)  # A non-capturing group matching either a whitespace or end of string 
(\s|$)    # A capturing group matching either a whitespace or end of string
```

Answer (score 6):

This replaces GBP if it's preceded by the start of a string or a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (which the start of a string already is), and after GBP comes a numeric value or a word boundary:

```
re.sub(u'\bGBP(?=\b|\d)', u'£', text)
```

This removes the need for any unnecessary backreferencing by using a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Inclusive enough?

Comment: "\d+": the plus sign is not necessary

Comment: You're right, in fact most regex engines don't allow for repetition or  and some only fixed repetition trough {MIN,MAX} inside lookarounds making the \d+ invalid. I was aware but completely missed it so thanks i've edited accordingly :)

Comment: @Martijn, that only applies to lookBEHINDs; lookAHEADs have no such limitation (at least, not in any flavor I'm familiar with).

Comment: it actually does apply to some flavor(s) for lookaheads i'll have to dig up the exact name though. It's much more common for lookbehinds indeed. There are fewer flavors that DO allow quantifying within lookbehinds to those that DONT. Whereas (much) less flavors DONT allow for it in lookahead then DO

Comment: Note `r'\bGBP'` matches `(BGP)`, `.GPB`, `=GBP` and many others which can be very useful but does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `'(^|\W)GBP([\W\d])'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why not?

```
re.sub(u'^\W*GBP...
```

matches the start of the string, 0 or more whitespaces, then GBP...

*edit*: Oh, I think you want alternation, use the `|`:

```
re.sub(u'(^|\W)GBP...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always trim leading and trailing whitespace from the token before you search if it's not a matching/grouping situation that requires the full line.

Answer (score 0):

It works in Perl:

```
$text = 'GBP 5 off when you spend GBP75';
$text =~ s/(\W|^)GBP([\W\d])/$1\$$2/g;
printf "$text\n";
```

The output is:

```
$ 5 off when you spend $75
```

Note that I stipulated that the match should be global, to get all occurrences.