# Replace @replies in tweet text with HTML hyperlinks without replacing email addresses

Tags: php, regex, twitter, hyperlink, preg-replace

I'm detecting `@replies` in a Twitter stream with the following PHP code using regexes.  In the first pattern, I replace @replies at the beginning of the string; in the second, I replace the @replies which follow a space.

```
$text = preg_replace('!^@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)!', '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>', $text);
$text = preg_replace('! @([A-Za-z0-9_]+)!', ' <a href="http://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>', $text);
```

How can I best combine these two rules without false flagging `email@domain.com` as a reply?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525635/regular-expression-match-start-or-whitespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, on a second thought, not flagging whatever@email means that the previous element has to be a "non-word" item, because any other element that could be contained in a word could be signaled as an email, so it would lead:

```
!(^|\W)@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)!
```

but then you have to use $2 instead of $1.

Comment: also, this will eat the whitespace before the @

Comment: This will work for most email addresses, but technically can break, since mailbox names can contain a much wider array of characters than a perl word can (which is a-z, 0-9, underscore)

Comment: @BaileyP: The idea was to avoid e-mail addresses.

@hop: You're right, so the substituted string should include also the $1 in front of the link.

Comment: @diegosevilla - I know.  That's my point.  The set of allowable characters for email-address mailboxes names is far greater than what \w includes.  In other words, it WILL break for something like test.@example.com (which is valid) since \W will match the period.

Comment: I'm okay with the occasional breakage, I think.

Comment: Full line of PHP code, with a small change so it doesn’t eat any whitespace before the @: `$str = preg_replace('!(^|\W)@([\w]+)!', ' <a href="http://twitter.com/$2" rel="nofollow">@$2</a>', $str);`

Answer (score 2):

Since the `^` does not have to stand at the beginning of the RE, you can use grouping and `|` to combine those REs.

If you don't want re-insert the whitespace you captured, you have to use "positive lookbehind":

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s)@(\w+)/',
    '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>', $text);
```

or "negative lookbehind":

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)@(\w+)/',
    '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>', $text);
```

...whichever you find easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do the combination

```
$text = preg_replace('!(^| )@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)!', '$1<a href="http://twitter.com/$2" target="_blank">@$2</a>', $text);
```

Comment: Read the post, please. "How can I best combine these two rules without false flagging email@domain.com as a reply?"

Comment: Man, I'm sorry - I TOTALLY missed that part of the post - I didn't mean to waste a reply.

Answer (score 0):

Use alternation in the non-capturing group and forget the space if matched using `\K`.

Use `(\w+)` to capture alphanumeric and underscore characters.

The fullstring match will retain the `@`.
Capture group 1 will contain the text after the `@`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8lVBu))

```
echo preg_replace(
         '/(?:^| \K)@(\w+)/',
         '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">$0</a>',
         $tweet
     );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
preg_replace('%(?<!\S)@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)%', '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>', $text);
```

`(?<!\S)` is loosely translated to "no preceding non-whitespace character". Sort of a double-negation, but also works at the start of the string/line.

This won't consume any preceding character, won't use any capturing group, and won't match strings such as `"foo-@host.com"`, which is a valid e-mail address.

Tested:

```
Input = 'foo bar baz-@qux.com bee @def goo@doo @woo'
Output = 'foo bar baz-@qux.com bee <a href="http://twitter.com/def" target="_blank">@def</a> goo@doo <a href="http://twitter.com/woo" target="_blank">@woo</a>'
```

Comment: You need to use a different sentinel character; your bangs conflict.  e.g. '#(?<!\S)@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)#'

Comment: still not working. also, the double negative is not necessary

Answer (score -1):

```
$text = preg_replace('/(^|\W)@(\w+)/', '<a href="http://twitter.com/$2" target="_blank">@$2</a>', $text);
```

Comment: closest to a nice answer, but this will eat the whitespace!

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use alternation,: so look for the beginning of a string or a space

```
'!(?:^|\s)@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)!'
```

Comment: You need to group your alternation. e.g. '!(?:^|\s)@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)!'

Comment: now it eats the whitespace and you can't even get to it in $1

Answer (score -2):

Hu, guys, don't push too far... Here it is :

```
!^\s*@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)!
```

Comment: This would not match a reply in a string like "hello, @ceejayoz!".